# Is there a Java API to list all actions given the AWS Action with wild character or AWS Service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am looking for a Java API to list all actions pertaining to an AWS Service or given an action containing wild character such as `ec2:Create*` in the below IAM policy -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Create*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The output should be -

```
CreateFpgaImage
CreateImage
CreateCapacityReservation
CreateFleet
CreateKeyPair
CreateLaunchTemplate
CreateLaunchTemplateVersion
CreatePlacementGroup
CreateReservedInstancesListing
CreateSecurityGroup
CreateSpotDatafeedSubscription
CreateTags
```